# Fix: 'App only installing once, if I uninstall and install again, it gives an error'

Tags: android, debugging, react-native

I am trying to install an APK file into my device. The application installs and runs perfectly for the first time, but if I uninstall the app and then try to install it, it shows an error
I searched this problem and found a similar one but in that, the app was still being listed as NOT INSTALLED FOR THIS USER which is not there in my case
The only solution to this problem is if I uninstall the app using UNINSTALL APP FOR ALL USERS option in settings, which I don't think is a good solution for the users.

I am creating an Android app using React Native, the app is completely built and signed using the steps mentioned in the docs. However, when I install this app for the first time, it runs perfectly, but a uninstall and install again throws an error "App not installed".
The only solution that I found was to use the option "Uninstall the app for all users" in the settings, which I don't think is an optimal solution since this app is not meant to be uploaded on Play Store as it is only for the internal employees of the company and app will be distributed as an APK file.
From what I have understood as of know, this problem is due to the fact that the application files were not completely removed after the last uninstall, and UNINSTALLING FOR ALL USERS does that and app installs again

I wanted to know if there was any workaround or any changes that can be made into the code which would make sure that app once uninstalled can be easily installed again without any such error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this question wasn't answered by anybody, but I found out the answer myself after a long session of debugging and searching the forums.
In my case, the issue was because Google Play Protect was blocking the install
I think maybe it was because even after uninstalling some signature files of the previous app were still left on the device and next time installing the app threw an error, but uninstalling the app for all users deleted everything from the device
To resolve this

1. Go to Google Play Store
2. From the left side panel, go to Google Play Protect and disable it

That should do the trick